# Error regarding Python empty list. UnboundLocalError

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I ran my code and it's showing the following errors.

```
File "C:/Users/PC/PycharmProjects/untitled/test2.py", line 36, in clustering
min_num = y.index(min(y))
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'y' referenced before assignment
```

The error is showing up for the empty list 'list = []' too. The following is my code.

```
 def clustering(self, parsedData=np.genfromtxt("0.txt"), iterCount=0, k=0, centroids=None):
    if centroids is None:  # when no centroids are passed in, randomize the centroids
        np.random.seed(1111)
        centroids = []
        for i in range(k):
            centroids.append(np.random.randint(0, len(parsedData[0])))  # adding centroid numbers from dataset
            new1 = [[] for x in range(len(centroids))]
            y = []
            lis = []
        for i in parsedData[0]:
            for j in centroids:
                x = []
                if i == j:
                    for k in (parsedData.ix[i][2:4]):  # calculating and adding the actual centroids to a list
                        x.append(k)
                    lis.append(x)
        centroids = lis

        iterCount += 1
        for a in range(iterCount):
            if a == 0:
                for i in (parsedData[0]):
                    for j in range(len(centroids)):
                        dist = 0
                        dist += distance(parsedData.ix[i, 2:4],
                                         centroids[j])  # same process except, centroids are not random
                        y.append(dist)
                    min_num = y.index(min(y))
                    new1[min_num].append(int(i))
                    y = []
```

Comment: When `k==0` the loop `for i in range(k):` doesn't execute, so you never set `y=[]`. Why are you doing those assignments in a loop?

Comment: And you overwrite `new1` every time through the loop. Are you sure those 3 lines are supposed to be in the loop in the first place?

Answer (score -1):

When `k` is `0` (the default) your first loop (that could initialize `y`) never runs. So depending on the value of `centroids`, you'll either try to call `y.append` (accessing a `y` that was never assigned) or `y.index(min(y))` (same problem).

Analyze your code, figure out what `y` represents, and make sure it has a reasonable value before you try to use it.

The same problem should occur with `lis`, since `k` of `0` also fails to assign to `lis`, making the assignment `centroids = lis` read from an unbound `lis` name.

Answer (score -1):

These 3 lines are not indented correctly:

```
            new1 = [[] for x in range(len(centroids))]
            y = []
            lis = []
```

They're inside the `for i in range(k):` loop, but they shouldn't be, as they have no dependency on `i`. When `k == 0`, none of those assignments will be done, so the later code that tries to use those variables gets an error.

Unindent them 1 level.

```
 def clustering(self, parsedData=np.genfromtxt("0.txt"), iterCount=0, k=0, centroids=None):
    if centroids is None:  # when no centroids are passed in, randomize the centroids
        np.random.seed(1111)
        centroids = []
        for i in range(k):
            centroids.append(np.random.randint(0, len(parsedData[0])))  # adding centroid numbers from dataset
        new1 = [[] for x in range(len(centroids))]
        y = []
        lis = []
        ...
```

I'm not sure, but I think all the rest of the function is also indented wrong. Only the code that fills in `centroids` randomly should be in `if centroids is None:`